# How to find complete empty row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on one dataset in which I need to find complete empty columns from the dataset.
example:

```
A   B   C   D
nan nan nan nan
1   ss  nan  3.0
2   bb  w2  4.0
nan nan nan nan
```

Currently, I am using

```
import pandas as pd
nan_col=[]
for col in df.columns:
    if df.loc[df[col].isnull()].empty !=True:
        nan_col.append(col)
```

But this is capturing null values in the specified columns but I need to capture null rows.

```
expected Answer: row [0,3]
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to proceed to identify a complete null row in the dataframe.

Answer (score 6):

You can compare if all rows has missing values by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and then get index values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
L = df.index[df.isna().all(axis=1)].tolist()
#alternative, if huge dataframe slowier
#L = df[df.isna().all(axis=1)].index.tolist()
print (L)
[0, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `dropna` with `set` and `sorted`, I get the index after dropping the rows with `NaNs` and then also get the index of the whole dataframe and use `^` to get the values that aren't in both indexes, then after the I use `sorted` to sort the list and convert it into a list, like the below:

```
print(sorted(set(df.index) ^ set(df.dropna(how='all').index)))
```

If you might have duplicate index, you can do a `list` comprehension to iterate through the whole `df`'s index, and add the value to the `list` comprehension if the value isn't in the `dropna` index, I also use `enumerate` so that if all indexes are the same (all duplicate index), it would still work, like the below:

```
idx = df.dropna(how='all').index
print([i for index, i in enumerate(df.index) if index not in idx])
```

Both codes output:

```
[0, 3]
```